# Does beaker support run job without re-install operating system?

Tags: beaker-testing

beaker is a automation tool: https://beaker-project.org/. Does beaker support run job/task without re-install operating system in a machine?

Answer (score 0):

In a scheduled job Beaker will always re-install the machine, there is currently no way to avoid that. (I would like to implement optionally skipping the installation for a recipe, one day.)

If you want to run Beaker tasks on some existing system without re-installing it, maybe because you are testing some changes to a task and you don't want to wait for Anaconda over and over again, you can use the [restraint](http://restraint.readthedocs.org/en/latest/commands.html#restraint) harness. It has a [client mode command](http://restraint.readthedocs.org/en/latest/commands.html#restraint) where you can give it a Beaker recipe XML file and it will run it.

Restraint can also fetch task source from git directly, which is particularly handy if you are testing your own patches for a task.

You can grab pre-built restraint packages from the [Beaker harness yum repos](https://beaker-project.org/yum/harness/).